# Why is my JSON created via the `Factory` different from the one i am getting from `API`.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

My mock `stub` get's `escaped` properly, but the API response
                                            one is not getting `escaped`.

Below is my Mock stub factory.

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :account do |f|
        f.name {Faker::Name.name}
        f.description {Faker::Name.description}     
    end

    factory :account_json, class: OpenStruct do
    send :'@type' , "accountResource"
        createdAt "2014-08-07T14:31:58"
        createdBy "2"
        updatedAt "2014-08-07T14:31:58"
        updatedBy "2"
        accountid "2055"
        name "Test"
        description "Something about Test"
        disabled "false"
    end

end
```

Below is spec where i am building my Factory stub and trying to compare it with API response.

```
it "can find an account that this user belongs to" do 
    account = Account.find( id: 2055, authorization: @auth )        
    hashed_response = FactoryGirl.build(:account_json).marshal_dump.to_json
    expect(account.to_json).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);
end
```

API Response and Stub

FactoryGirl Stub

```
expected: "\"{\\\"@type\\\":\\\"accountResource\\\",\\\"createdAt\\\":\\\"2014-08-07T14:31:58\\\",\\\"createdBy\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"updatedAt\\\":\\\"2014-08-07T14:31:58\\\",\\\"updatedBy\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"accountid\\\":\\\"2055\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Something about Test\\\",\\\"disabled\\\":\\\"false\\\"}\"
```

API response

```
got: "{\"@type\":\"accountResource\",\"createdAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58\",\"createdBy\":2,\"updatedAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58\",\"updatedBy\":2,\"accountid\":2055,\"name\":\"Test\",\"description\":\"Something about Test\",\"disabled\":false}"
```

Why is my JSON created via the `Factory` different from the one i am getting from `API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting `hashed_response` `to_json` twice - once in the second and once in the third line of your spec. Remove one of the `to_json` method calls.

For example:

```
2.0.0-p247 :005 > {"@type" => "accountResource"}.to_json
 => "{\"@type\":\"accountResource\"}" 
2.0.0-p247 :006 > {"@type" => "accountResource"}.to_json.to_json
 => "\"{\\\"@type\\\":\\\"accountResource\\\"}\""
```

Comment: That worked, but still fails... the last key and value appears to be strange... pastie.org/9457936

Comment: the disabled propety's value false has backslash

Comment: That is because you are telling your spec to expect the string `"false"` whereas you are getting the FalseClass `false`.

Comment: How can i compare with attributes alone... right now its checking for both key and value... how can i check whether it has the attributes alone.

Comment: @UnderTaker after parsing the json into a ruby Hash you can call #keys to get a list of the keys... Is that what you want?

Comment: pastie.org/9459619 here we are comparing the json with our stub. I want the keys of API response to be compared with my stub.